# Spring property overriding with env creates double entry

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In application.yml I have:

```
topics:
  names:
    user: topic1
    user-payment: topic2
```

I am binding it to the `@ConfigurationProperties` and have `Map<String, String>`:

```
"user" -> "topic1"
"user-payment" -> "topic2"
```

However, if I provide ENV variable for my application:

`TOPICS_NAMES_USER_PAYMENT=topic3`

in my map, I can see the additional entry (although the normal one is overridden too)

```
"user" -> "topic1"
"user-payment" -> "topic3"
"user.payment" -> "topic3"
```

For `TOPICS_NAMES_USERPAYMENT=topic3` I will get:

```
"user" -> "topic1"
"user-payment" -> "topic3"
"userpayment" -> "topic3"
```

Is it possible to fix it? It will work with `TOPICS_NAMES_USER-PAYMENT` as env key, but I cannot do this. I just want to get rid of this additional entry.

Comment: topic1/2/3 are placeholders for real names of topic. Structure is valid as I wrote in question

Comment: There’s no way for Spring to know whether you want USERPAYMENT, U_SERPAYMENT, or any of the other 9 choices, given the variable USERPAYMENT. Just use the whole word.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar the problem is not that I cannot override my property, the problem is that in my map I have additional property which I don't want

Comment: I think the issue is not that it adds additional key but the issue is that despite adding addtional key it changes value of the original key which honestly it just shouldn't. 

It's understandable that Spring doesn't know how to parse USER_PAYMENT and it properly sets is as user.payment, the problem is that it updates the value of user-payment as well which seems like a bug

Comment: @Mestru Based on documentation of Spring it should override that and it is doing that properly. The problem is spring cannot currently fetch that it shouldn't add additional keys, but maybe this is done for optimization